# Hot Reload VanilaJS with Flask App or create bundle.js on every src change

Tags: javascript, flask, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

- I would like to make changes to JavaScript modules and have those changes packaged into /dist/bundle.js in realtime
- As long as this /dist/bundle.js gets created automatically when src modules are changed, my problem is solved (I can just refresh page and have my change reflected)
- I currently run: *npm run dev* after every change and refresh the url
- Alternatively is there a plugin for webpack-dev-server that allows me to start *wepack-dev-server --mode development*; but still leverage the Flask app running on localhost:5000 with /dist/bundle.js
- I am trying to increase my workflow speed, so any tactical hack will help

.

Tree Structure

```
    static
        ├───data
        │   └───@es#_ohlc_15min.json
        ├───dist
        │   └───bundle.js   (created by webpack)
        └───src
            ├───index.js
            ├───img
            ├───models
            └───views
    template
        └───index.html

    app.py  (flask app with routes)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tradingview_charts",
  "main": "static/src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lightweight-charts": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: ['./static/src/index.js'],

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static'),
        filename: 'dist/bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './static',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tradingview Lightweight Charts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css') }}?{{ nowts }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chart chart__candlestick" id="main_candlestick"></div>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='dist/bundle.js') }}?{{ nowts }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webpack --watch
```

Does the trick for me.

However my entry modules, with all the packaged imported modules is rather large.

It makes using --watch rather unreliable whenever I make a minor change. As a result, manually running "npm run web" after a subjectively major change on my part